# Vertical ruler in RCP applications

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Eclipse text editors has this nice vertical rulers at both sides where bookmarks and annotations are shown with little dots, so that you navigate real quick to the line.
I've got to do something similar, but not with the text editor, - with some large list or a table. How would you go about it? Is there anything in eclipse RCP I can re-use? Or just take Canvas and start drawing stuff with SWT wizardry? I really don't want to reinvent the wheel, having a model would be real great. There must be something which already exists..

Can anyone give me a direction where to dig?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but this answer isn't enough for me to go on. I would like to link a table to an annotation ruler too, to highlight and jump to specific rows. How did you do this?

Comment: I was unable to find anything to re-use, but I have learned the idea behind it and implemented my own. I needed a ruler next to a table with vast number of records in it. The ruler highlights certain records and provides a link. I've made my own ruler which is a simple composite sitting next to a table. There is a shared model of data which is displayed in the table and same model is used by the ruler to paint the dots. Ruler does calculation of coordinates and paints colored bars. See the screenshot here: http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/images/screens/full/layout.png.

Comment: Oh I see, very nice and complicated. I shall give it a go.

Comment: Not a rocket science, but nasty piece of code. But the results are very rewarding. It gives an overview and fast navigation.

Comment: I really need a nice way to quickly jump to hot spots in  a table, and obviously using eclipse so often that was the first idea they came to mind.

Comment: Well, make a model which can be used by the ruler to calculate the coordinates and position few pixel wide strip of color. Then, when clicked on it - scroll your table to the item. What I do is having a list of Annotation objects as a model for the ruler to paint the points. Each annotation holds real table item which I then focus on when ruler is clicked.

Comment: I'm getting there, but I'm trying to do those yellow popup things with no luck, what is the component used for those do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look how this zone (Ruler) is setup in the [`CompilationUnitEditor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/CompilationUnitEditor.java.htm).

It is an [`IVerticalRuler`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/IVerticalRuler.java.htm) (see [JavaDoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/IVerticalRuler.html), and one [standard implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/VerticalRuler.java.html)), actually used by a [`SourceViewer`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/SourceViewer.java.htm): that last class actually set up the vertical ruler zones.

Comment: That was it. The only problem in VerticalRuler is that it's permanently coupled with text editors and all the plugins which come with it, this is a huge useless dependency in my case. But the source code of default implementation actually helped me to extract the gist. Now I've got huge data table with a ruler mapping everything nicely. Thanks!